What does DRMS OTS mean in a notam
MULTIPLE DRMS OTS ON RWY 34R/16L. 9/3 EAST/WEST SIDE. 8/4 EAST
SIDE. 6/6 EAST/WEST SIDE. 1/11 EAST SIDE. 18 APR 22:01 2024 UNTIL 31 MAY
23:59 2024. CREATED: 18 APR 22:01 2024
I have looked everywhere and all I could find for DRMS was Distance Root Mean Square which doesn't make any sense. This is a notam for OTBH.

I would say it reads multiple Distance Remain Marker(S) are out of service.

Welcome to Aviation.SE! That answer makes complete sense, especially given the rest of the info in the NOTAM. Good deduction!
